# How to reload a img attr "src" after ajax call without knowing the file name from the image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I have this html:

```
<div class="d-inline-flex">
    <img id="reloadIMG" class="p-3 mt-5 imgP" onDragStart="return false" <?php echo htmlentities($avatar, \ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?>> 
    <input type="file" id="uploadAvatar" name="uploadedAvatar"> 
</div>
```

the value of `$avatar`:

```
$pathFolderAvatar = 'user/'.$folder.'/avatar/*';
$imgUserPastaAvatar = glob($pathFolderAvatar)[0] ?? NULL;
if(file_exists($imgUserPastaAvatar)){
    $avatar = 'src='.$siteURL.'/'.$imgUserPastaAvatar;
}else{
    $avatar = 'src='.$siteURL.'/img/avatar/'.$imgPF.'.jpg';
}
```

and the script to send a ajax call to my file that process the file upload request:

```
$(function () {
    var form;
    $('#uploadAvatar').change(function (event) {
        form = new FormData();
        form.append('uploadedAvatar', event.target.files[0]);
    });
    $("#uploadAvatar").change(function() { 
      $("#loadingIMG").show();
      var imgEditATTR = $("div.imgP").next().attr("src");
      var imgEdit = $("div.imgP").next();
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://example/test/profileForm.php',
          data: form,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data) {
            $("#loadingIMG").hide();
            $(imgEdit).attr('src', imgEditATTR + '?' + new Date().getTime());
          }
      });
    });
});
```

i tried to force the browser to reload the img on success ajax call `$(imgEdit).attr('src', imgEditATTR + '?' + new Date().getTime());` but the `selector` from the `var` `imgEdit` and `imgEditATTR` is not working:

`console.log(imgEdit);` result: `w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(0)]`
`console.log(imgEdit);` result: `undefined`;

Why is it happening, and how to fix?

I know that there's a bunch of questions about reload img, but on these questions there's not a method to reload a image without knowing the file name. I checked so many questions and this is what the answears say:

```
d = new Date();
$("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
```

On my case i don't know the file name, because it's generated randomly on `profileForm.php` with `mt_rand()`:

```
$ext = explode('.',$_FILES['uploadedIMG']['name']);
$extension = $ext[1];
$newname = mt_rand(10000, 10000000);
$folderPFFetchFILE = $folderPFFetch.'avatar/'.$newname.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
//example of the result: 9081341_1546973622.jpg

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedAvatar']['tmp_name'], $folderPFFetchFILE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return file name in response to your AJAX request and use it in success block to update src attribute of img tag

So your profileForm.php will look something like

```
 $ext = explode('.',$_FILES['uploadedIMG']['name']);
    $extension = $ext[1];
    $newname = mt_rand(10000, 10000000).'_'.time();
    $folderPFFetchFILE = $folderPFFetch.'avatar/'.$newname.'.'.$extension;
    //example of the result: 9081341_1546973622.jpg
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedAvatar']['tmp_name'], $folderPFFetchFILE);
    echo $newname // you can also send a JSON object here
    // this can be either echo or return depending on how you call the function
```

and your AJAX code will look like

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://example/test/profileForm.php',
      data: form,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
        $("#loadingIMG").hide();
        $(imgEdit).attr('src', data);
      }
  });
```

Comment: I realized that my selector was wrong, i changed the value of my `var` to `var imgEdit = $("img.imgP").before()` and it's kinda "working", now it's updating the `img` `src` but as the `(data)` is returning the entire `html` of my page, so the `src` of the image is looking like this: `src="<!doctype html><html><heade>..."`

Comment: Are you sending you AJAX request to same page where you are uploading it? 
In that case, add a if() block at top of that page which only deals with your file upload, and return from execution after echoing your file name. that will skip further execution and you wont get entire HTML response. If possible, share your profileForm.php file

Comment: it's working! i realized that it was happening because i had `header()` on `profileForm.php`

Answer (score 0):

Let `profileForm.php` return the generated filename:

```
$ext = explode('.',$_FILES['uploadedIMG']['name']);
$extension = $ext[1];
$newname = mt_rand(10000, 10000000);
$folderPFFetchFILE = $folderPFFetch.'avatar/'.$newname.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedAvatar']['tmp_name'], $folderPFFetchFILE);

echo json_encode(['filename' => $folderPFFetchFILE]);
```

Then in the callback of your `POST` request:

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#loadingIMG").hide();
  $(imgEdit).attr('src', data.filename);
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed... and i saw no erros on console.log (unless about the `console.log(imgEditATTR);`)

Comment: @Natalie check what's inside `data` in the success callback. Also, check the HTTP response in the Network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: i don't check HTTP response offten, so what should i see in there? I clicked on the file `profileForm.php` from the ajax call on the Network tab and i saw on the `Form Data` ta this text: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedIMG"; filename="10154480_10153165259039460_6422933530386579090_n.jpg"` this looks like a different ramdoly generated file name, this is not the current file name that is being saved on my folder.

Comment: And for `alert(data)` on success, it shows my entire html on the pop up